# Trying to print the first character of a string

Tags: c

I'm trying to print the first letter of a string, in this case the word is "radar". The issue that I am having is that it is printing out the whole string. What is confusing me is when I change `str[0]` to `str[1]` it will print "adar". Why is it removing the first letter and printing the rest instead of the other way around?

```
void first(char *str)
{
  char *initial;
  initial = &(str[0]);

  printf("Its first character is %s\n", initial);

  return;

}
```

Comment: use `%c` to print a character rather than a string.

Comment: `str`, and thus `str+0`, points to `radar`. `str+1` therefore points to `adar`. Nothing is removed.

Comment: keeping that one as a canonical duplicate. I'm sure this has been asked before, but I like the shortness of the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The format specifier for a character is `%c`.
You can get the first character from `str` by just dereferencing it: `str[0]`

So in summary you can just do this:

```
void first(char *str)
{
    printf("Its first character is %c\n", str[0]);
}
```

> Why is it removing the first letter and printing the rest instead of the other way around?

`str[1]` gives you the second character in `str`. In your code you defined `initial` as a pointer set to the address of that second character. You then treated `initial` as a string (by printing it with the `%s` specifier) so you got the second character and everything after it, up to the `\0` character at the end of the string.

Comment: I don't think that `printf("Its first character is %s\n", str[1]);` would do what you say: "hen you get the second character and everything after it, up to the \0 character at the end of the string".  %s would try and use the value as a pointer and str[1] would just be a ASCII character, and you'd either get a compiler error or a run-time error.

Comment: Correct @bruceg. I was trying to explain why the OP was seeing that result when he was using it as a string (i.e. with `initial` defined as a `char*`). I'll edit to explain more clearly.

Comment: Thank you! That makes much more sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
  char *initial;
  initial = &(str[0]);
in this initial is pointer of character and you store the address of   first character by writing &(str[0]).
if you write %s that means print string from address store in initial and when you store address of second element like &(str[1]) so it print string from 2nd letters. 

So if you want to print only one character you have to write %c instead of %s.


  printf("Its first character is %c\n", initial);
```